# POST values available to all the PHP pages that are INCLUDED in the POST TO page?

Tags: php, post

If you use `POST` to send FORM data to a PHP page, are the `POST` values available to use in all the PHP pages that are INCLUDED in the POST TO with the `PHP INCLUDE`?

Example in the POSTED TO PAGE:

```
<?php include 'otherpage.php'; ?>
```

Would I be able to use the POST value that was sent to the 'POSTED TO Page' in 'otherpage.php'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope. 
>   [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 3):

When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs.  So if you can access POST at the same line of your include then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually you should be able to access these variables.